# how to write costomselect query which returns Future in Flutter/moor

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'm developing apps by flutter/moor.
but I don't get how to write custom query which returns Future<List> class object.

I could wrote query which returns Stream class object.
but it's not enough.
does anyone now how to change it to one which returns Future class.

query I wrote is bellow

```
db.dart

Stream<List<QuestionHeader>> selectQuestionHeaderByKey(int businessYear,int period, int questionNo) {
    return
      customSelect(
        'SELECT *'
            +'From question_Headers '
            +'WHERE business_Year = ? '
            +'AND period = ? '
            +'AND question_No = ?;',
        variables: [Variable.withInt(businessYear),Variable.withInt(period),Variable.withInt(questionNo)],
        readsFrom: {questionHeaders},
      ).watch().map((rows) {
        return rows
            .map((row) => QuestionHeader(
            businessYear:row.readInt('businessYear')
            ,period:row.readInt('period')
            ,questionNo:row.readInt('questionNo')
            ,subjectId:row.readInt('subjectId')
            ,compulsoryType:row.readInt('compulsoryType')
            ,answerType:row.readInt('answerType')
            ,questionText:row.readString('questionText')
            ,numberAnswer:row.readInt('numberAnswer')
            ,correctType1:row.readInt('correctType1')
            ,correctType2:row.readInt('correctType2')
            ,correctType3:row.readInt('correctType3')
            ,favorite:row.readBool('favorite')
        )).toList();
      });
  }
```

this works but I need Future<List> class to return.

Comment: so do not use `watch()`

Comment: thank you for editing and comment

I just removed "watch()"
but the error cause that says "A value of type 'Selectable<dynamic>' can't be returned from the method 'selectQuestionHeaderByKey' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<QuestionHeader>>'. (Documentation)"
how can I resolve it??

Comment: read the official documentation https://pub.dev/documentation/moor/4.2.1/moor/Selectable-class.html or moor tutorial: https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/writing_queries/#select-statements

Comment: thank you for putting URL
I checked the site and I think I should replace watch() to get()
I did but the error bellow occurs
"The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'."

Comment: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: thank you for the answer
but I still don't get how to map the Future object
according to official document, Future class doesn't have map method so error occurs

Comment: I wrote like this and resolved

~~

  Future<List<QuestionHeader>> selectQuestionHeaderByKey(int businessYear,int period, int questionNo) {
[Variable.withInt(businessYear),Variable.withInt(period),Variable.withInt(questionNo)],
        readsFrom: {questionHeaders},
      ).map((row) => QuestionHeader(
            businessYear:row.readInt('business_year')
            ,period:row.readInt('period')
~~~~
~~~~
            ,favorite:row.readBool('favorite')
        )).get();
  }
~~~

thank you so much.

Comment: *"Future class doesn't have map method so error occurs"* - `map` is a `List`'s method, so try: `List list = await customSelect(...); return list.map(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.watch()` use `.get()`